# Working with columns and rows python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

i am trying to collect data from pandas dataframes. In the Screenshot you will see a part of how the database is built.

[image: Database]

So now I want to analyze for the same hhid other columns. For the same hhid I want to compute the away time. I want to select the first "from home" row and read the start value. Then this should not be overwritten again for the same hhids. After that I want the end value of the last "to home" entry and then compute the difference between them. I tried to implement that, but the most time the read start value of from home gets overwritten and the differences are not the same.

Here is my routine:

```
wid=1
for i in range(0,len(dataframe)):
             
    if (i+1 >= len(dataframe)):
              break  
    if (
               dataframe['hhid'].values[i] == dataframe['hhid'].values[i+1] or                                   
               dataframe['hhid'].values[i] == dataframe['hhid'].values[i-1]
      ):
       
       
       if (
              
               dataframe['w01'].values[i] == 'from Hause' and
               wid >= dataframe['wid'].values[i]
         ):
               
               bla = dataframe['wid'].values[i]
               
               start =  dataframe['st_std'].values[i]
               print('start',start)
               wid = dataframe['wid'].values[i]
       
            
       if (
               dataframe['w04'].values[i] == 'to Hause' 
              
          ):
        
           end =  dataframe['en_std'].values[i]
           print('end',end)
           dataframe['awaytime'].values[i]= (end-start)
           
           if end-start < 0:
               dataframe['awaytime'].values[i]= (start-end)+1
           
       else:
           continue
       
    if(dataframe['hhid'].values[i] != dataframe['hhid'].values[i+1]):
            if (i+1 >= len(dataframe)):
              break 
            wid=dataframe['wid'].values[i+1]
            
return dataframe
```

Any ideas how to do it correctly?

## EDIT

sample of data in excel format. Unfortunately I am not allowed to upload the full dataset:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/af3wb7fcsqhukvz/Export_db_awaytime.xlsx?dl=0

Comment: Can you update your post to include a sample of data that's not a picture so that we could copy it to work with?  To go along with your sample of input data having a table showing your desired output would be helpful as well.

Comment: Edited in the post.

Comment: A link is better than a picture, but still not ideal.  Including a handful of representative data points, not the whole dataset, just enough to illustrate what the data looks like along with what you would expect the output for that data to look like would make it easier for others to help you.

Comment: The proper way is to use groupby on hhid and shift to get the differences. Would be happy to help you in chat. https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176354/questions-51423538

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved the problem. I added an counter to hold the first value of from home. The values I get are good.

FYI the code:

```
counter=0
test_counter=0
from_home=0
for i in range(0,len(dataframe)):

    if (i+1 >= len(dataframe)):
              break  
    """Check for same hhid"""
    if (
               dataframe['hhid'].values[i] == dataframe['hhid'].values[i+1] or                                   
               dataframe['hhid'].values[i] == dataframe['hhid'].values[i-1]
       ):

       """Check for first departure"""
       if (

               dataframe['w01'].values[i] == 'from home' and
               counter<=test_counter
         ):

               start =  dataframe['st_std'].values[i]
               #print('start',start)
               from_home=1
               counter+=1
       """Check way home"""    
       if (
               dataframe['w04'].values[i] == 'to home' and
               from_home==1
          ):

           end =  dataframe['en_std'].values[i]

           dataframe['awaytime'].values[i]= (end-start)

           if end-start < 0:
               dataframe['awaytime].values[i]= (start-end)+1

    """Check when another hhid is next entry"""   

    if(dataframe['hhid'].values[i] != dataframe['hhid'].values[i+1]):
            if (i+1 >= len(dataframe)):
              break 
            counter=0
            from_home=0
```